# How I can ignore feature in behat?

Tags: laravel, bdd, behat

I am using `behat` with `laravel`.
I have some features which I want to ignore in tests. 
So I have inside features folder:
 - a.feature
 - b.feature
 - c.feature

I want to exclude feature c from testing. At the moment if I want to exclude feature c from tests I have to rename it - for example to "c.feature.tmp".
Is there some more intelligent way ... something like in java or .NET we have `@Ignore` annotation.

Comment: Check if making test suites is appropriate for you: http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the features you don't want to test a tag like `@notesting` and then run behat like this.

`behat --tags '~@notesting'`

The `~` sign is a `NOT` operator.

Or like @grzegorz-zadja mentioned you can also use [test suites](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html).

In your feature file right above your Feature: you can put tags. Just add `@notesting` there. See the [documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#tags).

Comment: how I can mark feature that is for no testing?
In other words what I have to do in order to make it excludable with '@notesting' tag?

Comment: @gandra404 in your feature file right above your `Feature:` you can put tags. Just add `@notesting` there. See the documentation: http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#tags

Comment: thanks! I will try it and then accept if works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tag filters supports three logical operators:

Tags separated by `commas` will be combined using the `OR` operation
Tags separated by `&&` will be combined using the `AND` operation
Tags preceded by `~` will be excluded using the `NOT` operation

For example:

- `$ behat --tags '@orm,@database'`
- `$ behat --tags 'ticket,723'`
- `$ behat --tags '@orm&&@fixtures'`
- `$ behat --tags '~@javascript'`
- `$ behat --name 'number has'`

The first command will run only features or scenarios which have the `@orm` OR `@database` tag (or both).

The second command will run only features or scenarios which have the `@ticket` OR `@723` tag (or both).

The third command will run only features or scenarios with both the `@orm` AND `@fixtures` tags (must have both).

The fourth command will run all features or scenarios NOT tagged with `@javascript`. (All except those tagged `@javascript`)

The fifth command will run only features and scenarios that contain `number has` in their title.

---

[gherkin filters](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html#gherkin-filters)